# Fold and sum groups only for one of many types

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

At first i have a table of payments, relevant data looks like this

```
id     | price  | type     | ts
------ | -------|----------|---------------------------
1      | 50     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:01:00.000000
2      | 15     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:02:00.000000
3      | 5      | Refund   | 2016-06-24 16:03:00.000000
4      | 10     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:04:00.000000
5      | 20     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:05:00.000000
6      | 40     | Withdraw | 2016-06-24 16:06:00.000000
7      | 30     | Withdraw | 2016-06-24 16:07:00.000000
8      | 15     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:08:00.000000
9      | 25     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:09:00.000000
```

what i want is fold all rows with type = 'Payment' to form of sum, begin and end period, all other must be the same, so result is looks like this

```
id     | price  | type     | begin                     | end 
------ | -------|----------|---------------------------|---------------------------
null   | 65     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:01:00.000000| 2016-06-24 16:02:00.000000
3      | 5      | Refund   | 2016-06-24 16:03:00.000000|
null   | 30     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:04:00.000000| 2016-06-24 16:05:00.000000
6      | 40     | Withdraw | 2016-06-24 16:06:00.000000|
7      | 30     | Withdraw | 2016-06-24 16:07:00.000000|
null   | 40     | Payment  | 2016-06-24 16:08:00.000000| 2016-06-24 16:09:00.000000
```

also it would be useful if it had some flags like is row is grouped, and support for limiting final result

right now i stopped at trying row_number, group by, lag, and other, cant find the right way

**UPD**: link to sql fiddle with working result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3cfea/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  You can use the difference of row numbers trick to get the groups for the payments.  Then you can use a `case` to only apply it for the payments themselves (and not the other values).  This looks like:

```
select (case when type <> 'payment' then id) as id,
       sum(price) as price,
       min(type) as type,
       min(ts) as begin,
       max(case when type = 'payment' then ts end) as end
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by type order by id)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when type = 'payment' then grp end),
         (case when type <> 'payment' then id end);
```